# Is it legal to copy themes between different linux distros?

Tags: centos, linux-mint, file-copy, theme

I installed SentOS 8 with Xfce and there is not many gtk themes in it. Can I simply copy them from Mint 20 Xfce? Is it legal to copy the contents of the two folders `/usr/share/icons/` and `/usr/share/themes/` between different linux distros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn’t be any problem in the majority of cases; exceptions might include themes with branding (but I haven’t checked).

You’ll find the license terms for the various files involved on most if not all distributions, included in the distribution. For Debian-based distributions, find the packages involved using `dpkg -S ${file}`, then look at `/usr/share/doc/${package}/copyright`. For Fedora- or RHEL-based distributions, find the packages involved using `rpm -q --whatprovides ${file}`, then look at `/usr/share/licenses/${package}` (check the output of `rpm -qL ${package}` if necessary.

Comment: Obviously, it's vanishingly unlikely that anyone would ever bother trying to prosecute, but do you really think there might be even a theoretical possibility where copying a file from one system I own to another system I own would be illegal? As I understand it, the OP would simply copy a theme from one machine to another, not include it in a new distribution. Surely installing the theme onto your own personal machine woujldn't constitute copyright infringement, right? What if the two OSs were installed on the same machine?

Comment: **For personal use only, will depend on where you are**: Do you have fair use, what are your fair use criteria. However if you have a fully free distro like Debian, then you can do it any way (so long as you follow the licence conditions).

Comment: @terdon yes, I was considering using rather than distributing; but one might run into trademark license considerations, which are different (but IANAL and all that, and I haven’t actually checked). I’m playing it safe, the important part of the answer is how to examine the licenses.